# When I use a font in my game, do I have to include its license in the credits?

Tags: legal, copyright, fonts, licensing

For example, if I use this font from Google Fonts:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans

This font is licensed under Apache License 2.0

But regardless of the license, if it allows commercial use, do I have to include a notice or the license in the credits? (assuming that I didn't modify the font)

Comment: _"But regardless of the license"_ What you can do and can't do with a font is generally written in the license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribution requirements of a work are part of the licence. You have to refer to it (or your lawyer who has been paid to read it for you) to know what must be done.

If your question is actually "must the attribution be in the credits as opposed to some other place?", the answer is "unless there is some requirement in the license, no". Movies would put this in the credits because that's the only accessable place to a theatre viewer, but plenty of software just includes a file or directory of notices of licenses invoked. You can put it in an about screen or a licenses screen in the options menu (android phones and one smart thermostat i've seen do this) or whatever works for you, as long as it's reasonably findable by anyone looking for it.